# When should tables NOT be compressed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, compression

We have two servers. One we just compressed, but I took over this little project and [this guy says some tables are not good candidates](http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2008/12/22/fun-with-data-compression-in-sql-server-2008/). As with many others, performance is -critical-. 
Is it accurate to say that some tables shouldn't be compressed? If so, what is a general threshold to look for?
I ran his script to check for each objects reads/writes, but since this looks like a history, not what's occurred during a time frame, this might not be an accurate way to gauge that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also take a look at [this whitepaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894051%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) written by the SQL CAT team. Take note of who all reviewed that document too, it is very well written.

The whitepaper will explain that since we are talking about data compression there is some data that will compress better than other. I believe the section on *Application Workload* has information for some of your questions, is goes over the performance implications found when using data compression. My advice is going to be to test it. That is really the only way you will find out for sure if it will benefit or hurt your application/system.

A snippet from the whitepaper points out some data that does not benefit from data compression:

- Columns with numeric or fixed-length character data types where most
  values require all the bytes allocated for the specific data type
- Not much repeating data
- Repeating data with non-repeating prefixes
- Data stored out of the row
- FILESTREAM data

Comment: Awesome link Shawn, I think this is exactly what I needed to read

Comment: Had to research the same thing at a previous employer...came in very handy

Comment: Hm, I must say - I doubt the first item. I get 75% compression ratio sometimes on tables which have only fixed length data types (numeric - financial transaction data). There is not a single variable length data type in those.

Comment: @TomTom I don't think the intent of the list in the whitepaper is to point out data that "cannot be compressed" but more towards what you do not usually get any benefit in compressing. However, every environment is different and the main reason I mentioned to test it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add to Shawn's answer, that tables with frequent writes (updates, inserts, deletes) are bad candidates as well, because it takes time to apply compression for every transaction. Eg. staging tables before accepting new data should not be compressed. It is faster to load data and compress it afterwards, rather than load data into compressed table.